# Access: Fill in data (date) from another when entered and empty

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

Working with MS Access 2016. 
I have a form with multiple textboxes. I want one of my textboxes (tbx_outTSDatum_BQC) to be automatically filled -if entered and empty- with the value of another textbox (tbx_inTSDatum_BQC). This code does nothing:

```
Private Sub tbx_outTSDatum_BQC_Enter()
    If Me.tbx_outTSDatum_BQC.Value = Empty Then Me.tbx_outTSDatum_BQC.Value = Me.tbx_inTSDatum_BQC.Value
End Sub
```

Changing the event from Enter() to GotFocus() does not help. How can I get this working? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is *Null* to check for:

```
If IsNull(Me!tbx_outTSDatum_BQC.Value) Then 
    Me!tbx_outTSDatum_BQC.Value = Me!tbx_inTSDatum_BQC.Value
End If
```

Comment: Thank you! Perfect! If I would have known that "Empty" was the mistake, I would have been able to google it.